# Derivative of function $f(x) = \sqrt{2x}+ \sqrt{2/x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, exponential-function

The derivative of function

$$f(x) = \sqrt{2x}+ \sqrt{2/x}$$

Here's what I did,

$$f(x) = \sqrt{2x}+ \sqrt{2/x}
\\ = (2x)^{1\over2} + ({2\over x})^{1 \over 2}\\\\$$

$$f'(x)={1\over 2}(2x)^{-{1\over 2}}(2) + {1\over 2}({2 \over x})^{-{1 \over 2}}({2\over x^2})
\\=2x^{-{ 1\over 2}}+({1\over x})^{-{1\over 2}} ({2\over x^2})$$

I don't know what is going on!

Please help what I did wrong and what I should do

Thank you.

Or Can I see the steps how it's solved?

Comment: **Hint**: Rewrite $$\bigg( \frac{2}{x} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ as $$\sqrt{2} x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

Comment: @Mattos Deleted my answer, you beat me to the point and more clearly at that :P

Comment: @Mattos what difference does it make? How?? Why?

Comment: $f(x)=2^{1/2}\left(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}\right)$, or $f({\mathrm e}^{2t})=2^{3/2}\cosh(t)$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @NikolajK

Comment: @didgocks Simplifies after squaring both sides and then differentiating.

Comment: @didgocks I suggested you put it in a different form so that you can differentiate as you would for $x^{n}$.

Comment: @didgocks: You may use the chain rule, assuming you know how to take the derivative of $x^r$ of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Wait, I can use quotient rule instead of chain rule for this right?? @Mattos

Comment: @didgocks Yes you can. By the way, your original result is almost correct, you just made a mistake in your second last to last lines with the $2$. Notice that

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \bigg( \frac{2}{x} \bigg)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \cdot \frac{2}{x^{2}} = \bigg( \frac{2}{x} \bigg)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \frac{1}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: @Mattos would you mind if you just show me the steps as answer?? I can't get anything right now

Comment: @didgocks Did my comment above make sense?

Comment: @Mattos so the answer is $$2x^{-{1\over 2}}+ {1 \over \sqrt{2x}^{3\over 3}}$$ Is this correct??

Comment: @didgocks I'll make a post

Answer (score 2):

You have

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sqrt{2x} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \\
&= (2x)^{\frac{1}{2}} + (2x^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot (2x)^{\frac{-1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot -2x^{-2} \cdot (2x^{-1})^{\frac{-1}{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Is there any way it could be rewritten so that it matches the answer page? $$({\sqrt{2} \over 2})x^{-{3 \over 2}} (x-1)$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \bigg) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \bigg( \frac{x - 1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \bigg) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} x^{\frac{-3}{2}} (x - 1)$$